# Parameter count mismatch with Invoke?

Tags: c#, winforms, parameters, delegates, invoke

The code block below results in the error: TargetParameterCountException was unhandled by user code.  Parameter count mismatch.

```
    public void AddListViewItem(string[] Data)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Action<string[]>(AddListViewItem), Data);
        }
        else
        {
            ListViewData.Items.Add(Data[0]).SubItems.AddRange
            (
                new string[]
                { 
                    Data[1],
                    Data[2],
                    Data[3],
                }
            );
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the signature of `AddListViewItem`?

Comment: It's right there. He's calling it recursively.

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error occurs because of array covariance; an array of strings is assignable to `object[]`. This causes the `Invoke` method to treat each element of the `string` array as if it should be an argument to the `AddListViewItem` method.

Here's a fix:

```
Invoke(new Action<string[]>(AddListViewItem), new object[] {Data});
```

(or)

```
Invoke(new Action<string[]>(AddListViewItem), (object)Data);
```

This makes it crystal-clear to `Invoke` that the target method takes a *single* parameter.

Comment: @Ani, Could you explain what is array covariance? better with an example. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me crazy. Your first example worked well in my situation. I was passing an object array, but the invoke method isn't smart enough to handle it as-is.  Example...

`.Invoke(mysource, new object[] {myobjectarray});`

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE information:

If you are using **Windows Server 2008 R2**, take a look at Windows Update for **.Net Framework 4.5.1** for **Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 based systems KB2858725**. For me, after installed this update fixed this issue.